# FailedToLaunchApplicationException when automating a website by Coded UI test builder

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests

I want to Automate a website by coded UI test builder, for example, open Chrome, then open Facebook, type user and password, then login.

I created these steps:

```
public void openchrome()
    {

        // Launch '%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
        ApplicationUnderTest chromeApplication = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.openchromeParams.ExePath, this.openchromeParams.AlternateExePath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// openfb - Use 'openfbParams' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void openfb()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinClient uINewTabClient = this.UINewTabGoogleChromeWindow.UINewTabButton.UINewTabClient;
        WinEdit uIAddressandsearchbarEdit = this.UINewTabGoogleChromeWindow.UIItemGroup.UIAddressandsearchbarEdit;
        WinWindow uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow = this.UIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow;
        #endregion

        // Click 'New Tab' client
        Mouse.Click(uINewTabClient, new Point(44, 6));

        // Type 'https://www.facebook.com' in 'Address and search bar' text box
        uIAddressandsearchbarEdit.Text = this.openfbParams.UIAddressandsearchbarEditText;

        // Click 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up - Google Chrome' window
        Mouse.Click(uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow, new Point(535, 85));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// username - Use 'usernameParams' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void username()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinWindow uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow = this.UIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow;
        WinMenu uIAutofillMenu = this.UIItemWindow.UIItemClient.UIAutofillMenu;
        WinControl uIFacebookLogInorSignUDocument = this.UINewTabGoogleChromeWindow.UIFacebookLogInorSignUDocument;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up - Google Chrome' window
        Mouse.Click(uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow, new Point(1275, 167));

        // Type '{NumPad1}' in 'Autofill' popup menu
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIAutofillMenu, this.usernameParams.UIAutofillMenuSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);

        // Type '{NumPad4}{NumPad3}{NumPad5}{NumPad4}{NumPad5}{NumPad9}b' in 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up - Google Chrome' document
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIFacebookLogInorSignUDocument, this.usernameParams.UIFacebookLogInorSignUDocumentSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// password - Use 'passwordParams' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void password()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinWindow uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow = this.UIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow;
        WinMenu uIAutofillMenu = this.UIItemWindow.UIItemClient.UIAutofillMenu;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up - Google Chrome' window
        Mouse.Click(uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow, new Point(1476, 177));

        // Type '{NumPad1}{NumPad2}{NumPad3}' in 'Autofill' popup menu
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIAutofillMenu, this.passwordParams.UIAutofillMenuSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// login
    /// </summary>
    public void login()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinWindow uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow = this.UIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up - Google Chrome' window
        Mouse.Click(uIFacebookLogInorSignUWindow, new Point(1647, 177));
    }
```

but when I create any website Automation, I got this Error when I create it by the Coded UI test builder :

> Failed CodedUITestMethod1  TestProject3    Test method TestProject3.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   ...
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException: "The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reason:
>
> You do not have sufficient privileges for this application." File:
>   %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.

and this also

> Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked
>   control visible and retry the action.

Comment: don't keep us in suspense. What is the exception!?

Comment: "The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reasons:
1) Another instance of the application is already running and only one instance can be running at a time.
2) The application started another process and has now stopped. You may need to launch the process directly.
3) You do not have sufficient privileges for this application." File: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Coded UI. I recall you had to run as administrator to automate IE. Maybe Chrome also now requires elevated privileges but this is a wild guess.

Comment: ok thanks I will try your suggestion now

Comment: this time I got this error:

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.

Comment: That's encouraging. It just means one or more of the selections your are doing don't find a control. What I used to do when I needed to know how to find a control was to run a recorded test and then look at the code it generated.

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: every time I get a new error I do not know why

Comment: Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. Additional Details

Answer (score 0):

If you could edit your post with the new information of the comments that should help with archiving purposes.

The "FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException" is because there is either another control in front of the one you are attempting to click, or it is in a different logical location than where it seems to be.

Try instead clicking on the control as a point by doing:

```
Mouse.Click(control.ToPoint());
```

where ToPoint is an extension method that takes in a control, and then gets the x and y coordinates of the control.BoundingRectangle.